# Time complexity of BFS algorithm if sorting the queue is necessary

Tags: time-complexity, breadth-first-search

In BFS, you typically have something like

```py
while q:
  popped_node = q.popleft()
  res.append(do_work(popped_node))
  for child in popped_node.children:
    q.append(child) return res
```

But say for some reason you needed to iterate over the children in order based on some key, so you would have

```py
while q:
  popped_node = q.popleft()
  res.append(do_work(popped_node))
  for child in sorted(popped_node.children, key=lambda x: x._id):
    q.append(child) return res
```

Typically the time complexity of BFS is O(N), number of nodes. How does adding this sorting portion affect the time complexity?

Comment: Complexity of BFS is not O(n), its O(n^2) for adjacency matrix representation and O(V+E) when speaking in terms of vertices and edges respectively in a adjacency list representation.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider there are V vertices in a graph G with E edges.
Looking at you code:

```
// This loop runs V times
while q:
  popped_node = q.popleft()
  res.append(do_work(popped_node)) // assuming this is O(1)

  // this loop runs O(Ei + Eilg(Ei)) times, where Ei is number of edges connected with current vertex
  // Eilg(Ei) is upper bound for sorting algorithm
  for child in sorted(popped_node.children, key=lambda x: x._id):
    q.append(child)     
  return res
```

Time complexity is as follows:

= O(1) + O(E<sub>1</sub>) + O(E<sub>1</sub>lgE<sub>1</sub>) + O(1) + O(E<sub>2</sub>) + O(E<sub>2</sub>lgE<sub>2</sub>) + ... O(1) + O(E<sub>V</sub>) + O(E<sub>V</sub>lgE<sub>V</sub>)

= V*(O(1) + E<sub>i</sub>) + ∑<sub>i=1</sub><sup>V</sup> O(E<sub>i</sub>lgE<sub>i</sub>)

= O(V + E) + ∑<sub>i=1</sub><sup>V</sup> O(E<sub>i</sub>lgE<sub>i</sub>)

This extra term **∑<sub>i=1</sub><sup>V</sup> O(E<sub>i</sub>lgE<sub>i</sub>)** in time complexity is due to sorting.

Assuming there is only single edge b/w any two vertices, in worst case E<sub>i</sub> -> V i.e. a fully connected graph
Time complexity can then be given as:
= O(V + E) + ∑<sub>i=1</sub><sup>V</sup> O(E<sub>i</sub>lgE<sub>i</sub>)

= O(V + E) + ∑<sub>i=1</sub><sup>V</sup>O(VlgV)

= O(V + E) + O(V<sup>2</sup>lgV)

Two points to mention here:

- If sorting utilises sorting algorithm other than comparison sort, like counting sort, bucket sort etc. with linear complexity then ∑<sub>i=1</sub><sup>V</sup> O(E<sub>i</sub>lgE<sub>i</sub>) can be replaced by  ∑<sub>i=1</sub><sup>V</sup>O(E<sub>i</sub>) = O(E), which evaluates to O(V + E).
- Although for adjacency matrix this is a good tight bound, but for adjacency list(or sparse graph) this will be a loose upper bound.

Comment: This is holds only for comparison based sorting :)

Comment: @RinkeshP yes, the time complexity will depend on the sorting algorithm we use. If we use counting sort or bucket sort then it will be same as `O(V + E)` as the complexity for sort reduces to O(E)

Comment: @ManavChhibber Assume the sorting algorithm is nlogn

Comment: @TheRealFakeNews nlgn is same as EilgEi where n=Ei=the number of edges connected with vertex Vi. So runtime will be same as above `O(V + E) + O(V2lgV)`